# How to generate keyboard events?

Tags: python, keyboard-events

**short summary:**

I am trying to create a program that will send keyboard events to the computer that for all purposes the simulated events should be treated as actual keystrokes on the keyboard.

**original post:**

I am looking for a way to generate keyboard events using python.

Assume that the function receives a key that it must simulate pressing, like so:

```
keyboardevent('a') #lower case 'a'
keyboardevent('B') #upper case 'B'
keyboardevent('->') # right arrow key

def keyboardevent(key):
    #code that simulated 'key' being pressed on keyboard
```

The above are obviously examples, but what I am looking for is a library, module, or whatever, which I can use to simulate keyboard events.

*note*: This is different than sending characters to notepads, or inputting text into fields or such. I want the python script to simulate an actual keyboard event, the computer will think that there is really a keyboard event.

Extra Note:

I don't want to send keystrokes to the active window - I want the system to believe the keyboard's keys are being pressed, subtle difference, as some active-windows do not accept certain key-combinations, or if I wanted to use keyboard shortcuts for background processes through my script, they don't need to go through the active-window

So far I have looked at these things:

[Generate keyboard events for the frontmost application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318690/generate-keyboard-events-for-the-frontmost-application)

[How to generate keyboard keypress events through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868167/how-to-generate-keyboard-keypress-events-through-python)

Which were all about apple and didn't help at all.

And this:

[Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python)

Which seems like it might be what I need, but I can not find the library for it or any documentation.

I have searched more places as well, but have yet to find a solution.

Comment: The only thing I know of is [SendKeys](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys), which is Windows only.  This seems like a problem that will not have a cross-platform solution.  Why do you need this?  What problem are you solving?

Comment: For `X` platforms there is `xdotool` but is usually not installed by default. I believe reading the docs for `X` it should not be hard to write a minimal module in C that does what you want(I believe there was a `xsendkeys` program around some time ago).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thank you, this looks promising, but i would like to add, i will edit my question. i dont want to send keystrokes to the active window - i want system to believe the keyboard keys are being pressed, subtle difference, as some active-windows do not accept certain key-combinations, or if i wanted to use keyboard shortcuts for background processes through my script, they dont need to go through the active-window.

Comment: does it have to be pure python? does it have to be cross-platform?

Comment: @zenpoy for now, it does not need to be cross-platform, as long as it will work on windows XP, and 7, at least.. as for python. the code is going to be written in python. if the module/library/package/dll whatever can be interfaced from python effectively, it doesn't matter. ideally, it would be pure python, and cross-platform.

Comment: if you need something really complex that will work on any operating system or without os at all (e.g. in a BIOS menu) you need to do something like that: http://frank-zhao.com/cache/nehebkau.php

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It can be done using ctypes:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import time

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

INPUT_MOUSE    = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2

KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008

MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731
VK_TAB  = 0x09
VK_MENU = 0x12

# C struct definitions

wintypes.ULONG_PTR = wintypes.WPARAM

class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("dx",          wintypes.LONG),
                ("dy",          wintypes.LONG),
                ("mouseData",   wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("wVk",         wintypes.WORD),
                ("wScan",       wintypes.WORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(KEYBDINPUT, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        # some programs use the scan code even if KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE
        # isn't set in dwFflags, so attempt to map the correct code.
        if not self.dwFlags & KEYEVENTF_UNICODE:
            self.wScan = user32.MapVirtualKeyExW(self.wVk,
                                                 MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 0)

class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("uMsg",    wintypes.DWORD),
                ("wParamL", wintypes.WORD),
                ("wParamH", wintypes.WORD))

class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    class _INPUT(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (("ki", KEYBDINPUT),
                    ("mi", MOUSEINPUT),
                    ("hi", HARDWAREINPUT))
    _anonymous_ = ("_input",)
    _fields_ = (("type",   wintypes.DWORD),
                ("_input", _INPUT))

LPINPUT = ctypes.POINTER(INPUT)

def _check_count(result, func, args):
    if result == 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

user32.SendInput.errcheck = _check_count
user32.SendInput.argtypes = (wintypes.UINT, # nInputs
                             LPINPUT,       # pInputs
                             ctypes.c_int)  # cbSize

# Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode,
                            dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def AltTab():
    """Press Alt+Tab and hold Alt key for 2 seconds
    in order to see the overlay.
    """
    PressKey(VK_MENU)   # Alt
    PressKey(VK_TAB)    # Tab
    ReleaseKey(VK_TAB)  # Tab~
    time.sleep(2)
    ReleaseKey(VK_MENU) # Alt~

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AltTab()
```

`hexKeyCode` is the virtual keyboard mapping as defined by the Windows API. The list of codes is available on MSDN: [Virtual-Key Codes (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731)

Comment: i like this idea so far. i cant find a list of the VK_Key's, and could you maybe put up an example function call.

Comment: I add an simple method method to hit alt-tab.

Comment: i have been using this wonderfully, but now i have a small problem, hopefully you can help me - how can i move the mouse X,Y ?

Comment: haha, you have to use SetCursorPos :  win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))

Comment: you mean `ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos((x,y))` ?

Comment: yep it is the same function : win32api is an API to simplify the call to ActiveState C functions. More info here : http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32api.html

Comment: Next time point to duplicate question instead of duplicating the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289777/how-can-i-send-keyboard-commands-hold-release-simultanous-with-a-python-script

Comment: Stumbled upon this and was wondering if you could include an example for mouse input. I can't seem to use the class provided in your code correctly.

Comment: @lucasg the python console seems to catch the key pressed when I run the code. Ex: I tried using ctrl+A and ctrl+X  (from a shortcut in the context menu) on Chrome URL fields, but it doesn't work.

Comment: looks like this is windows specific. What's the alternative way for linux?

Comment: There is a library for that: 'keyboard'.

Comment: I can't seem to find a key code for the 'fn' key. Is there a way for me to activate it?

Answer (score 110):

For both python3 and python2 you can use [`pyautogui`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) (`pip install pyautogui`)

```
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey

press('a')
typewrite('quick brown fox')
hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
```

It's also crossplatform with Windows, OSX, and Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: `press` also works with media keys. I use it to mute my computer with `press('volumemute')`

Comment: This works, but it is slower than the accepted answer. (Too slow for my application, which requires very low latency.)

Comment: I have run into certain circumstances where applications will not accept commands via pyautogui, but cytpes seems to consistently work.

Comment: This pyautogui package is cross platform , works in mac and windows

Comment: @CharlesChow good call, that's worth noting for people so I added it to the answer. And it also works with Ubuntu (LTS and newer only according to the github)

Comment: it's not sending unicode characters.  (kubuntu 20, python 3.9)

Comment: ran the pip install, and in a Python3 script, it says that it can't find the module. - I tried listing it in Thonny (help('modules')) but it isn't listed, it IS listed with pip list, which shows PyAutoGUI 0.9.52 installed.  (I tried changing the case on the name in the import, no luck) Any ideas?

Comment: if I run the script as 'python2 test.py' it works, apparently this is a Python2 ONLY thing?

Comment: In case anyone else hits this, you have to run pip3 install pyautogui to install it for Python3... Unexpected (at least, by me, who is new to Python)

Comment: Yes, your system python is set to use python2, same with your system pip. This is completely unrelated to this module and I recommend looking up tutorials on using pip. Basically you should only ever use pip3.

Answer (score 16):

I tried lib [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) and it works good on Windows, Mac and Linux. Below line helps me switch tabs in browser:

```
keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+tab')
```

Comment: Works well on MAC as well. I have not tested linux, but it should work.

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad Yes. It works in linux too (tested in python 3).

Comment: Works on Raspberry Pi as well! I'm using my piano's left and center pedals to go 'left' or 'right' through my sheet music as I play!

Comment: But be aware, that you can use that library only being root

Comment: Requires root but is ~13 times faster than pyautogui with `pyautogui.PAUSE = 0`.

Answer (score 11):

user648852's idea at least for me works great for OS X, here is the code to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPost

# Python releases things automatically, using CFRelease will result in a scary error
#from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CFRelease

from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGHIDEventTap

# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281133/controlling-the-mouse-from-python-in-os-x
# and from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent


def KeyDown(k):
    keyCode, shiftKey = toKeyCode(k)

    time.sleep(0.0001)

    if shiftKey:
        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, True))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, True))
    time.sleep(0.0001)

    if shiftKey:
        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, False))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

def KeyUp(k):
    keyCode, shiftKey = toKeyCode(k)

    time.sleep(0.0001)

    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, False))
    time.sleep(0.0001)

def KeyPress(k):
    keyCode, shiftKey = toKeyCode(k)

    time.sleep(0.0001)

    if shiftKey:
        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, True))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, True))
    time.sleep(0.0001)

    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, False))
    time.sleep(0.0001)

    if shiftKey:
        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, False))
        time.sleep(0.0001)



# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes

def toKeyCode(c):
    shiftKey = False
    # Letter
    if c.isalpha():
        if not c.islower():
            shiftKey = True
            c = c.lower()

    if c in shiftChars:
        shiftKey = True
        c = shiftChars[c]
    if c in keyCodeMap:
        keyCode = keyCodeMap[c]
    else:
        keyCode = ord(c)
    return keyCode, shiftKey

shiftChars = {
    '~': '`',
    '!': '1',
    '@': '2',
    '#': '3',
    '$': '4',
    '%': '5',
    '^': '6',
    '&': '7',
    '*': '8',
    '(': '9',
    ')': '0',
    '_': '-',
    '+': '=',
    '{': '[',
    '}': ']',
    '|': '\\',
    ':': ';',
    '"': '\'',
    '<': ',',
    '>': '.',
    '?': '/'
}


keyCodeMap = {
    'a'                 : 0x00,
    's'                 : 0x01,
    'd'                 : 0x02,
    'f'                 : 0x03,
    'h'                 : 0x04,
    'g'                 : 0x05,
    'z'                 : 0x06,
    'x'                 : 0x07,
    'c'                 : 0x08,
    'v'                 : 0x09,
    'b'                 : 0x0B,
    'q'                 : 0x0C,
    'w'                 : 0x0D,
    'e'                 : 0x0E,
    'r'                 : 0x0F,
    'y'                 : 0x10,
    't'                 : 0x11,
    '1'                 : 0x12,
    '2'                 : 0x13,
    '3'                 : 0x14,
    '4'                 : 0x15,
    '6'                 : 0x16,
    '5'                 : 0x17,
    '='                 : 0x18,
    '9'                 : 0x19,
    '7'                 : 0x1A,
    '-'                 : 0x1B,
    '8'                 : 0x1C,
    '0'                 : 0x1D,
    ']'                 : 0x1E,
    'o'                 : 0x1F,
    'u'                 : 0x20,
    '['                 : 0x21,
    'i'                 : 0x22,
    'p'                 : 0x23,
    'l'                 : 0x25,
    'j'                 : 0x26,
    '\''                : 0x27,
    'k'                 : 0x28,
    ';'                 : 0x29,
    '\\'                : 0x2A,
    ','                 : 0x2B,
    '/'                 : 0x2C,
    'n'                 : 0x2D,
    'm'                 : 0x2E,
    '.'                 : 0x2F,
    '`'                 : 0x32,
    'k.'                : 0x41,
    'k*'                : 0x43,
    'k+'                : 0x45,
    'kclear'            : 0x47,
    'k/'                : 0x4B,
    'k\n'               : 0x4C,
    'k-'                : 0x4E,
    'k='                : 0x51,
    'k0'                : 0x52,
    'k1'                : 0x53,
    'k2'                : 0x54,
    'k3'                : 0x55,
    'k4'                : 0x56,
    'k5'                : 0x57,
    'k6'                : 0x58,
    'k7'                : 0x59,
    'k8'                : 0x5B,
    'k9'                : 0x5C,

    # keycodes for keys that are independent of keyboard layout
    '\n'                : 0x24,
    '\t'                : 0x30,
    ' '                 : 0x31,
    'del'               : 0x33,
    'delete'            : 0x33,
    'esc'               : 0x35,
    'escape'            : 0x35,
    'cmd'               : 0x37,
    'command'           : 0x37,
    'shift'             : 0x38,
    'caps lock'         : 0x39,
    'option'            : 0x3A,
    'ctrl'              : 0x3B,
    'control'           : 0x3B,
    'right shift'       : 0x3C,
    'rshift'            : 0x3C,
    'right option'      : 0x3D,
    'roption'           : 0x3D,
    'right control'     : 0x3E,
    'rcontrol'          : 0x3E,
    'fun'               : 0x3F,
    'function'          : 0x3F,
    'f17'               : 0x40,
    'volume up'         : 0x48,
    'volume down'       : 0x49,
    'mute'              : 0x4A,
    'f18'               : 0x4F,
    'f19'               : 0x50,
    'f20'               : 0x5A,
    'f5'                : 0x60,
    'f6'                : 0x61,
    'f7'                : 0x62,
    'f3'                : 0x63,
    'f8'                : 0x64,
    'f9'                : 0x65,
    'f11'               : 0x67,
    'f13'               : 0x69,
    'f16'               : 0x6A,
    'f14'               : 0x6B,
    'f10'               : 0x6D,
    'f12'               : 0x6F,
    'f15'               : 0x71,
    'help'              : 0x72,
    'home'              : 0x73,
    'pgup'              : 0x74,
    'page up'           : 0x74,
    'forward delete'    : 0x75,
    'f4'                : 0x76,
    'end'               : 0x77,
    'f2'                : 0x78,
    'page down'         : 0x79,
    'pgdn'              : 0x79,
    'f1'                : 0x7A,
    'left'              : 0x7B,
    'right'             : 0x7C,
    'down'              : 0x7D,
    'up'                : 0x7E
}
```

Comment: From my reading, it appears the key codes used here are mapped to **physical** keys, not virtual ones; and the physicality is based on the current keyboard layout. So if you used a different layout — DVORAK for example — this method will not continue to work the same way for any key that is not positioned identically in both layouts (will register key down/up for whatever symbol happens to be on the physical key in the new layout, not what was there in the old one). In my case, switching to sending key events programmatically using OSAscript didn't have that same downside.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem and made my own library for it that uses ctypes:

```
"""
< --- CTRL by [object Object] --- >
Only works on windows.
Some characters only work with a US standard keyboard.
Some parts may also only work in python 32-bit.
"""

#--- Setup ---#
from ctypes import *
from time import sleep
user32 = windll.user32
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
delay = 0.01

####################################
###---KEYBOARD CONTROL SECTION---###
####################################

#--- Key Code Variables ---#
class key:
        cancel = 0x03
        backspace = 0x08
        tab = 0x09
        enter = 0x0D
        shift = 0x10
        ctrl = 0x11
        alt = 0x12
        capslock = 0x14
        esc = 0x1B
        space = 0x20
        pgup = 0x21
        pgdown = 0x22
        end = 0x23
        home = 0x24
        leftarrow = 0x26
        uparrow = 0x26
        rightarrow = 0x27
        downarrow = 0x28
        select = 0x29
        print = 0x2A
        execute = 0x2B
        printscreen = 0x2C
        insert = 0x2D
        delete = 0x2E
        help = 0x2F
        num0 = 0x30
        num1 = 0x31
        num2 = 0x32
        num3 = 0x33
        num4 = 0x34
        num5 = 0x35
        num6 = 0x36
        num7 = 0x37
        num8 = 0x38
        num9 = 0x39
        a = 0x41
        b = 0x42
        c = 0x43
        d = 0x44
        e = 0x45
        f = 0x46
        g = 0x47
        h = 0x48
        i = 0x49
        j = 0x4A
        k = 0x4B
        l = 0x4C
        m = 0x4D
        n = 0x4E
        o = 0x4F
        p = 0x50
        q = 0x51
        r = 0x52
        s = 0x53
        t = 0x54
        u = 0x55
        v = 0x56
        w = 0x57
        x = 0x58
        y = 0x59
        z = 0x5A
        leftwin = 0x5B
        rightwin = 0x5C
        apps = 0x5D
        sleep = 0x5F
        numpad0 = 0x60
        numpad1 = 0x61
        numpad3 = 0x63
        numpad4 = 0x64
        numpad5 = 0x65
        numpad6 = 0x66
        numpad7 = 0x67
        numpad8 = 0x68
        numpad9 = 0x69
        multiply = 0x6A
        add = 0x6B
        seperator = 0x6C
        subtract = 0x6D
        decimal = 0x6E
        divide = 0x6F
        F1 = 0x70
        F2 = 0x71
        F3 = 0x72
        F4 = 0x73
        F5 = 0x74
        F6 = 0x75
        F7 = 0x76
        F8 = 0x77
        F9 = 0x78
        F10 = 0x79
        F11 = 0x7A
        F12 = 0x7B
        F13 = 0x7C
        F14 = 0x7D
        F15 = 0x7E
        F16 = 0x7F
        F17 = 0x80
        F19 = 0x82
        F20 = 0x83
        F21 = 0x84
        F22 = 0x85
        F23 = 0x86
        F24 = 0x87
        numlock = 0x90
        scrolllock = 0x91
        leftshift = 0xA0
        rightshift = 0xA1
        leftctrl = 0xA2
        rightctrl = 0xA3
        leftmenu = 0xA4
        rightmenu = 0xA5
        browserback = 0xA6
        browserforward = 0xA7
        browserrefresh = 0xA8
        browserstop = 0xA9
        browserfavories = 0xAB
        browserhome = 0xAC
        volumemute = 0xAD
        volumedown = 0xAE
        volumeup = 0xAF
        nexttrack = 0xB0
        prevoustrack = 0xB1
        stopmedia = 0xB2
        playpause = 0xB3
        launchmail = 0xB4
        selectmedia = 0xB5
        launchapp1 = 0xB6
        launchapp2 = 0xB7
        semicolon = 0xBA
        equals = 0xBB
        comma = 0xBC
        dash = 0xBD
        period = 0xBE
        slash = 0xBF
        accent = 0xC0
        openingsquarebracket = 0xDB
        backslash = 0xDC
        closingsquarebracket = 0xDD
        quote = 0xDE
        play = 0xFA
        zoom = 0xFB
        PA1 = 0xFD
        clear = 0xFE

#--- Keyboard Control Functions ---#

# Category variables
letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
shiftsymbols = "~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?"

# Presses and releases the key
def press(key):
        user32.keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0)
        sleep(delay)
        user32.keybd_event(key, 0, 2, 0)
        sleep(delay)

# Holds a key
def hold(key):
        user32.keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0)
        sleep(delay)

# Releases a key
def release(key):
        user32.keybd_event(key, 0, 2, 0)
        sleep(delay)

# Types out a string
def typestr(sentence):
        for letter in sentence:
                shift = letter in shiftsymbols
                fixedletter = "space"
                if letter == "`" or letter == "~":
                        fixedletter = "accent"
                elif letter == "1" or letter == "!":
                        fixedletter = "num1"
                elif letter == "2" or letter == "@":
                        fixedletter = "num2"
                elif letter == "3" or letter == "#":
                        fixedletter = "num3"
                elif letter == "4" or letter == "$":
                        fixedletter = "num4"
                elif letter == "5" or letter == "%":
                        fixedletter = "num5"
                elif letter == "6" or letter == "^":
                        fixedletter = "num6"
                elif letter == "7" or letter == "&":
                        fixedletter = "num7"
                elif letter == "8" or letter == "*":
                        fixedletter = "num8"
                elif letter == "9" or letter == "(":
                        fixedletter = "num9"
                elif letter == "0" or letter == ")":
                        fixedletter = "num0"
                elif letter == "-" or letter == "_":
                        fixedletter = "dash"
                elif letter == "=" or letter == "+":
                        fixedletter = "equals"
                elif letter in letters:
                        fixedletter = letter.lower()
                elif letter == "[" or letter == "{":
                        fixedletter = "openingsquarebracket"
                elif letter == "]" or letter == "}":
                        fixedletter = "closingsquarebracket"
                elif letter == "\\" or letter == "|":
                        fixedletter == "backslash"
                elif letter == ";" or letter == ":":
                        fixedletter = "semicolon"
                elif letter == "'" or letter == "\"":
                        fixedletter = "quote"
                elif letter == "," or letter == "<":
                        fixedletter = "comma"
                elif letter == "." or letter == ">":
                        fixedletter = "period"
                elif letter == "/" or letter == "?":
                        fixedletter = "slash"
                elif letter == "\n":
                        fixedletter = "enter"
                keytopress = eval("key." + str(fixedletter))
                if shift:
                        hold(key.shift)
                        press(keytopress)
                        release(key.shift)
                else:
                        press(keytopress)

#--- Mouse Variables ---#
                        
class mouse:
        left = [0x0002, 0x0004]
        right = [0x0008, 0x00010]
        middle = [0x00020, 0x00040]

#--- Mouse Control Functions ---#

# Moves mouse to a position
def move(x, y):
        user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)

# Presses and releases mouse
def click(button):
        user32.mouse_event(button[0], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        sleep(delay)
        user32.mouse_event(button[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        sleep(delay)

# Holds a mouse button
def holdclick(button):
        user32.mouse_event(button[0], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        sleep(delay)

# Releases a mouse button
def releaseclick(button):
        user32.mouse_event(button[1])
        sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### macOS

Here is the more complete version of [@Phylliida answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35373648/55075) in form of class with code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Script simulating keyboard events in macOS.
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13564851/55075

import sys
import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPost
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGHIDEventTap
#from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CFRelease # Python releases things automatically.

class Keyboard():
    shiftChars = {
        '~': '`',
        '!': '1',
        '@': '2',
        '#': '3',
        '$': '4',
        '%': '5',
        '^': '6',
        '&': '7',
        '*': '8',
        '(': '9',
        ')': '0',
        '_': '-',
        '+': '=',
        '{': '[',
        '}': ']',
        '|': '\\',
        ':': ';',
        '"': '\'',
        '<': ',',
        '>': '.',
        '?': '/'
    }


    keyCodeMap = {
        'a'              : 0x00,
        's'              : 0x01,
        'd'              : 0x02,
        'f'              : 0x03,
        'h'              : 0x04,
        'g'              : 0x05,
        'z'              : 0x06,
        'x'              : 0x07,
        'c'              : 0x08,
        'v'              : 0x09,
        'b'              : 0x0B,
        'q'              : 0x0C,
        'w'              : 0x0D,
        'e'              : 0x0E,
        'r'              : 0x0F,
        'y'              : 0x10,
        't'              : 0x11,
        '1'              : 0x12,
        '2'              : 0x13,
        '3'              : 0x14,
        '4'              : 0x15,
        '6'              : 0x16,
        '5'              : 0x17,
        '='              : 0x18,
        '9'              : 0x19,
        '7'              : 0x1A,
        '-'              : 0x1B,
        '8'              : 0x1C,
        '0'              : 0x1D,
        ']'              : 0x1E,
        'o'              : 0x1F,
        'u'              : 0x20,
        '['              : 0x21,
        'i'              : 0x22,
        'p'              : 0x23,
        'l'              : 0x25,
        'j'              : 0x26,
        '\''             : 0x27,
        'k'              : 0x28,
        ';'              : 0x29,
        '\\'             : 0x2A,
        ','              : 0x2B,
        '/'              : 0x2C,
        'n'              : 0x2D,
        'm'              : 0x2E,
        '.'              : 0x2F,
        '`'              : 0x32,
        'k.'             : 0x41,
        'k*'             : 0x43,
        'k+'             : 0x45,
        'kclear'         : 0x47,
        'k/'             : 0x4B,
        'k\n'            : 0x4C,
        'k-'             : 0x4E,
        'k='             : 0x51,
        'k0'             : 0x52,
        'k1'             : 0x53,
        'k2'             : 0x54,
        'k3'             : 0x55,
        'k4'             : 0x56,
        'k5'             : 0x57,
        'k6'             : 0x58,
        'k7'             : 0x59,
        'k8'             : 0x5B,
        'k9'             : 0x5C,

        # keycodes for keys that are independent of keyboard layout
        '\n'             : 0x24,
        '\t'             : 0x30,
        ' '              : 0x31,
        'del'            : 0x33,
        'delete'         : 0x33,
        'esc'            : 0x35,
        'escape'         : 0x35,
        'cmd'            : 0x37,
        'command'        : 0x37,
        'shift'          : 0x38,
        'caps lock'      : 0x39,
        'option'         : 0x3A,
        'ctrl'           : 0x3B,
        'control'        : 0x3B,
        'right shift'    : 0x3C,
        'rshift'         : 0x3C,
        'right option'   : 0x3D,
        'roption'        : 0x3D,
        'right control'  : 0x3E,
        'rcontrol'       : 0x3E,
        'fun'            : 0x3F,
        'function'       : 0x3F,
        'f17'            : 0x40,
        'volume up'      : 0x48,
        'volume down'    : 0x49,
        'mute'           : 0x4A,
        'f18'            : 0x4F,
        'f19'            : 0x50,
        'f20'            : 0x5A,
        'f5'             : 0x60,
        'f6'             : 0x61,
        'f7'             : 0x62,
        'f3'             : 0x63,
        'f8'             : 0x64,
        'f9'             : 0x65,
        'f11'            : 0x67,
        'f13'            : 0x69,
        'f16'            : 0x6A,
        'f14'            : 0x6B,
        'f10'            : 0x6D,
        'f12'            : 0x6F,
        'f15'            : 0x71,
        'help'           : 0x72,
        'home'           : 0x73,
        'pgup'           : 0x74,
        'page up'        : 0x74,
        'forward delete' : 0x75,
        'f4'             : 0x76,
        'end'            : 0x77,
        'f2'             : 0x78,
        'page down'      : 0x79,
        'pgdn'           : 0x79,
        'f1'             : 0x7A,
        'left'           : 0x7B,
        'right'          : 0x7C,
        'down'           : 0x7D,
        'up'             : 0x7E
    }

    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202629/55075
    def toKeyCode(self, c):
        shiftKey = False
        # Letter
        if c.isalpha():
            if not c.islower():
                shiftKey = True
                c = c.lower()
        if c in Keyboard.shiftChars:
            shiftKey = True
            c = Keyboard.shiftChars[c]
        if c in Keyboard.keyCodeMap:
            keyCode = Keyboard.keyCodeMap[c]
        else:
            keyCode = ord(c)
        return keyCode, shiftKey

    def KeyDown(self, k):
        keyCode, shiftKey = self.toKeyCode(k)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, True))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, True))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, False))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

    def KeyUp(self, k):
        keyCode, shiftKey = self.toKeyCode(k)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, False))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

    def KeyPress(self, k):
        keyCode, shiftKey = self.toKeyCode(k)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, True))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, True))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode, False))
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        if shiftKey:
            CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x38, False))
            time.sleep(0.0001)

    def Type(self, text):
        for key in text:
            self.KeyDown(key)
            self.KeyUp(key)
```

Here is the demo code using above class:

```
# DEMO
if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard = Keyboard()
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        keyboard.Type('Hello World!')
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        print("Error: Platform not supported!")
```

which will simulate typing `Hello World!` text on the current window.

You can run above code as a shell script. Check the link to the [`keyboard.py` file](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/scripts/python/Quartz/keyboard.py).

Answer (score 3):

**Windows only:** You can either use [Ironpython](http://ironpython.net/documentation/) or [a library](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html) that allows cPython to access the .NET frameworks on Windows. Then use the [sendkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class of .NET or the more general [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) to simulate a keystroke.

**OS X only:** Use [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net) then use use `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` call.

Full disclosure: I have only done this on OS X with Python, but I have used .NET sendkeys (with C#) and that works great.

Comment: I have used the .Net SendKeys from IronPython (for a desktop app's acceptance testing framework) and it worked great.

Comment: `python for .net` . a a solution, how would i then use the `sendkeys`. could you possibly give an example of this?

Answer (score 2):

Every platform is going to have a different approach to being able to generate keyboard events. This is because they each need to make use of system libraries (and system extensions). For a cross platform solution, you would need to take each of these solutions and wrap then into a platform check to perform the proper approach.

For windows, you might be able to use the [pywin32](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML) extension. [win32api.keybd_event](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32api__keybd_event_meth.html)

> **win32api.keybd_event**
>
> **keybd_event(bVk, bScan, dwFlags, dwExtraInfo)**
>
> Simulate a keyboard event
>
> Parameters
>
> bVk : BYTE  - Virtual-key code
>   bScan : BYTE  - Hardware scan code
>   dwFlags=0 : DWORD - Flags specifying various function options
>   dwExtraInfo=0 : DWORD  - Additional data associated with keystroke

You will need to investigate pywin32 for how to properly use it, as I have never used it.

Answer (score 2):

For Python2.7(windows32) I installed only [pywin32-223](https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/108187130/18e91208-1ae4-11e8-9a7a-9d9f74116105?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20180809%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180809T182519Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=1be44f60c36deb4316a656c333ec996aea9242134ecfab9021e5ee28286b1959&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dpywin32-223.win32-py2.7.exe&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream).
And I wrote simple python`s code:

```
import win32api
import time
import win32con

# simulate the pressing-DOWN "ARROW key" of 200 times

for i in range(200):
   time.sleep(0.5)
   win32api.keybd_event(0x28, 0,0,0)
   time.sleep(.05)
   win32api.keybd_event(0x28,0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)
```

It can be checked if you run the code and immediately go to the notepad window (where the text already exists) and place the cursor on the top line.

Comment: That exact same keybd_event function already exists in ctypes

Comment: ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x01, 0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

**regarding the recommended answer's code,**

For my bot the recommended answer did not work. This is because I'm using Chrome which is requiring me to use KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE in my dwFlags.

To get his code to work I had to modify these code blocks:

```
class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("wVk",         wintypes.WORD),
                ("wScan",       wintypes.WORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(KEYBDINPUT, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        # some programs use the scan code even if KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE
        # isn't set in dwFflags, so attempt to map the correct code.
        #if not self.dwFlags & KEYEVENTF_UNICODE:l
            #self.wScan = user32.MapVirtualKeyExW(self.wVk,
                                                 #MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 0)
            # ^MAKE SURE YOU COMMENT/REMOVE THIS CODE^

def PressKey(keyCode):
    input = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wScan=keyCode,
                            dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(input), ctypes.sizeof(input))

def ReleaseKey(keyCode):
    input = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wScan=keyCode,
                            dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(input), ctypes.sizeof(input))

time.sleep(5) # sleep to open browser tab
PressKey(0x26) # press right arrow key
time.sleep(2) # hold for 2 seconds
ReleaseKey(0x26) # release right arrow key
```

I hope this helps someone's headache!

Answer (score 0):

```
def keyboardevent():
     keyboard.press_and_release('a')
     keyboard.press_and_release('shift + b')
         
keyboardevent()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

class KBDIN(ctypes.Structure): _fields_ = (("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),("dwExtraInfo", ctypes.c_ulonglong))
class INPUT(ctypes.Structure): _fields_ = (("type", ctypes.c_ulong),("ki", KBDIN),("padding", ctypes.c_ubyte * 8))

def Press(key_code):   user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(INPUT(type=1, ki=KBDIN(wVk=key_code))), 40)
def Release(key_code): user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(INPUT(type=1, ki=KBDIN(wVk=key_code, dwFlags=2))), 40)
```

[Virtual key codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

Comment: Although code is useful, please also try to provide explanations of your code.