# How to type things with Python script

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to type things with Python using the win32api module. For example, if I want to type in the phrase "Happy Pi Day" into Microsoft Word every three seconds, I would have something like
import time

```
while 1:
    #types Happy Pi Day
    time.sleep(3)
```

However, I do not know what the command is for the "type" function.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events) may be helpful.

Comment: @AlexThornton That is a bold statement.

Comment: Is there any way to import VBScript?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys

Answer (score 1):

Is using win32api module a hard requirement? If not, you can use this:

https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/

Then its easy (more examples [here](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html)...):

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application.start("notepad.exe")
app.notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
```

Answer (score 0):

The type function is keyboard here is a link to help with that
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keyboard-module-in-python/
and to have something typed repeatedly you have this code

```
import pyautogui

import time
 
time.sleep(10)
 
for line in open("auto file.txt", "r"):
 
    pyautogui.typewrite(line)
     
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

here is a link
https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/auto-type-text-using-python