# Python - Passing keyboard input to a process

Tags: python, process, keyboard

Alright, so I got a question and hopefully you guys will be able to help me out with this.

Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

- Read what users write in Skype (using the Skype4Py lib).
- Convert specific lines from users into a keyboard event.
- Pass keyboard events to another (non-python-related) process (.exe) running locally.

Now the first two bullets are definitely doable but I'm not really sure how one would go about the last one. I'm assuming it's possible but I have absolutely no clue which module(s) I would need. If anyone has suggestions, modules or even examples for the last bullet I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you can get some hint here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events. By the way just curious, are you trying to develop some kind of a keylogger?

Comment: Your curiosity made me chuckle good sir. No, I'm not trying to develop some kind of keylogger. I plan on allowing users in a specific Skype group chat to write up specific lines that will be interpreted and converted to keyboard events, which in turn will be forwarded to a process. Resulting in people being able to 'control' the process I have running.

Also, I already had a look at that very same question prior to you posting it. Thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't help me with passing events to a process which is my only real obstacle.

Comment: One question as you mentioned that the keyboard event will be forwarded to a process. Is this process created by your script or is it a already running by default by the OS. It would be convenient if your could please add this info in your question regarding the process & what OS you are playing with? The more info you provide the more answers/suggestions you'll receive. :)

Comment: The process is already running by default by the OS, sorry for not mentioning that before.