# Send keys control + click in Selenium with Python bindings

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

I need to open link in new tab using Selenium.

So is it possible to perform ctrl+click on element in Selenium to open it in new tab?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13615802/1982962) can help.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use an `ActionChain` with `key_down` to press the control key, and `key_up` to release it:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://google.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('About')

ActionChains(driver) \
    .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
    .click(element) \
    .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
    .perform()

time.sleep(10) # Pause to allow you to inspect the browser.

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 12):

Two possible solutions:

**opening a new tab**

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

this is the solution for MAC OSX. In other cases you can use the standard Keys.CONTROL + 't'

**opening a new webdriver**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() #1st window
second_driver = webdriver.Firefox() #2nd windows
```

Comment: Nothing happens after `self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')` in Chrome

Comment: This answer, as stated, was tested on Firefox in 2015 not on Chrome . It is possible that new drivers versions require an update.  About Chromedriver compatibilities you can check  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and  https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp

Comment: I installed current driver version :(

Answer (score 0):

Below is what i have tried for Selenium WebDriver with Java binding and its working for me.
If you want to manually open the Link in New Tab you can achieve this by performing Context Click on the Link and selecting 'Open in new Tab' option. Below is the implementation in Selenium web-driver with Java binding.

```
Actions newTab= new Actions(driver);
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element"));

//Open the link in new window
newTab.contextClick(link).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Web-driver handles new tab in the same way to that of new window. You will have to switch to new open tab by its window name.

```
driver.switchTo().window(windowName);
```

You can keep track of window-names which will help you to easily navigate between tabs.

Answer (score 0):

By importing Keys Class, we can open page in new tab or new window with CONTROL or  SHIFT and ENTER these keys:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="login"]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ENTER)`

or

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="login"]').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ENTER)`

Answer (score 0):

For python, a good solution would be `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('<enter css selector here>').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN)`

After that, you should change windows so selenium could function in the new window

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]    
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
```

After using the window is useful to close it or go back to the original:

Close tab: `driver.close()`

Back to the original: `driver.switch_to_window(window_before)`

Also try `driver.switch_to.window()` if your Selenium version does not support the other one

Answer (score -4):

Following is working for me to open link in new tab :

```
   String link = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ENTER); 
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("yourlinktext")).sendKeys(link);
```

Above code is in java. you can convert to python easily I assume.

Please ask if have any query.