# I am trying to print a webpage using selenium (python) using chrome drivers. It launches the webpage but never prints it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\shantam\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)    
driver.get('https://careers.jpmorgan.com/careers/apply-experienced')#open the webpage
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "p").perform()
```

somehow the actionchain is not working.
please help.

Comment: If this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775759/send-keys-control-click-selenium

Comment: You can use JS to show the print dialog, but after that there isn't a way for Selenium to control that new dialog