# using "show more " to scrape data

Tags: python, parsing, button, screen-scraping, show

I've been trying to scrape data from a web page using python and so far so good. But the problem is that the page doesn't load everything right away, there is a " show more " button. So my script only scrape the first 10 items. 
I've looked at the site and there is nothing I can do with the url. I guess I have to post something to the server to get back the next items but I don't know what to post and how. There is my code :

```
res = requests.get('https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/recherche?motsCles=serveur&offresPartenaires=true&rayon=20&tri=0')

page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"media-body"})
url = []
for container in containers:
    url.append('https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr' +container.h2.a["href"])



for i in url:
    print(i)
email_list = []

for adress in url:
    print( ' testing ', adress)
    found = False
    detail = requests.get(adress)
    apply = bs4.BeautifulSoup(detail.text,"html.parser")
    apply_mail = apply.findAll("div",{"class":"apply-block"})
    if apply_mail == []:
        email_list.append('not found')
        continue

    email_raw = apply_mail[0].text
    for i in email_raw.splitlines():
        if '@' in i:
            email_list.append(i)
            found = True
    if not found:
        email_list.append('not found')



for i in email_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only data the that you can scrap with `Beuatifulsoup` or other `http` request library is that are available on start without `Javascirpt` in action. It is same as doing`curl $URL`, and parsing data.

One way to approch to this problem would be using `selenium` webdriver and
program same actions as user would have performed on browser.

More information can be found

- [Introduction to Web Scraping using Selenium](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72)
- [Send keys control + click in Selenium with Python bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775759/send-keys-control-click-in-selenium-with-python-bindings/27777509)
- [Webscraping with Selenium](http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/12/webscraping-with-selenium-part-1/)

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I did, I used selenium and it works just fine !