# Having trouble sending a keyboard command with Python

Tags: python, keyboard-events

This question is in reference to the following post:
[Question answered by georgesl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events)

I have copied all of the code that georgesl posted in his answer to the question; however, nothing is happening for me.  I am not sure where to start in order to diagnose the problem here.  I named the file where I copied all of georgesl's code into "keystud.py" I opened the python console and did the following:

```
Python 2.7.9
>>> from keystud import *
>>> AltTab()
>>> time.sleep(5); PressKey(0x48)
```

During the above sleep time of 5, I opened a blank notepad and placed the cursor in it so that the program would hopefully type an "h" in it.  I also created a python file with the same code and tried it by running it not using the console to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer to my question, (posted below), and Notepad worked fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to my own question.  I am running a 64 bit machine and I had to change the following.

changed (line numbers included for easy reference):

```
Line 4: SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput
```

To the following:

```
Line 4: SendInput = ctypes.windll.user64.SendInput
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: It is from the post that I referred to: "This question is in reference to the following post:"  Look at the first line in my question.  Maybe I should have just re-posted the code from the link, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
type('h')
```

You can use commands like Key.ENTER or Key.TAB to hit the Enter or Tab button etc.