# how to stop itertools.count() using keyboard press event?

Tags: python

In the following program

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count():
    print (i)
```

I wanted to stop this event using keyboard press events.

Comment: You will have to put something in the loop to detect a keyboard press event has occurred, and break if so.

Comment: If you want this for arbitrary keys (not just ctrl+c), then this related (duplicate?) question could be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38754175/1639625

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://effbot.org/zone/stupid-exceptions-keyboardinterrupt.htm) exception and then get out:

```
import itertools

try:
    # Stay inside the loop until Ctrl+C is pressed
    for i in itertools.count():
        print (i)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
# Go on...
```