# Generate keyboard event based on ASCII character

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to write a function that will receive an ASCII character and will generate a keyboard event based on it.
KeyboardEvent is the function I'm trying to implement:

```
from msvcrt import getch
key= ord(getch()) #getting the ASCII character for a key that was pressed
KeyboardEvent(key)
def KeyboardEvent(key):
    #code that simulates the key (that the ASCII character represents) being pressed on keyboard
```

I've tried looking for answers and the closest I've gotten to is this question
[Generate keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events)
However, the code that the answer suggested is not based on ASCII characters and doesn't meet my needs.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you already found should work fine for ASCII, it does for me. In that code there are functions like:

```
def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
          ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode))
user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

and for regular ASCII keyboard characters you are safe to pass the value from your code

```
key=ord(getch())
```

straight to those functions, as the hexKeyCode parameter.