# How can I simulate a key press in a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

The scenario is, I have a Python script which part of it is to execute an external program using the code below:

`subprocess.run(["someExternalProgram", "some options"], shell=True)`

And when the external program finishes, it requires user to "press any key to exit".

Since this is just a step in my script, it would be good for me to just exit on behalf of the user.

Is it possible to achieve this and if so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate keyboard events in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["someExternalProgram", "some options"], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

If you want to capture the output and error log

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    
p = Popen(["someExternalProgram", "some options"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = p.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

remember that the input has to be a bytes object

Comment: I think we need the 'b' before '\n' because it looks like input requires a byte-like object. I tried `p.communicate(input=b'\n')` and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked, edited my comment. `p.communicate()` also does a `p.wait()`.