# Python popen() to exit while loop when see python prompt

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm running a python program `(my_file.py)` which at the end of process becomes python prompt. I thus can't get out of the `while` loop. `p.stdout.readline()` waits for something to happen.

Any suggestion how to break the `while` loop. `p.pole()` will also probably remain `null` as there is some background automation associated with `my_file.py`.

I need the break condition to be ">>>" prompt with no activity.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys, time
for iteration in range(25):
    p=Popen(r"python my_file.py",
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            shell=False,
            encoding='utf-8',
            errors='replace',
            universal_newlines=True)
    while True:
        realtime_output = p.stdout.readline()
        if realtime_output == '': #and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        else:
            print(realtime_output.strip(), flush=True)
    print("--------------- PythonSV session for {} iteration is complete -----------\n\n".format(iteration + 1))
    #subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /T /PID %i" % p.pid, shell=True)
    Popen.terminate(p)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried following option where read() trying to find '\n>>>' is the break condition and it worked.

> ```
> import subprocess
> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
> import sys, time
> for iteration in range(30):
>     p=Popen(["python", r"my_file.py"],
>             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
>             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
>             shell=False,
>             encoding='utf-8',
>             errors='replace',
>             universal_newlines=True)
>     output = ''
>     while not output.endswith('\n>>>'):
>         c=p.stdout.read(1)
>         output+=c
>         sys.stdout.write(c)
>     Popen.terminate(p)
>     time.sleep(1)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: instead of breaking on `realtime_output == ''`, break when you get a Python prompt

Option 2: instead of using `readline()`, use non-blocking read on the pipe, though [it's pretty involved to get working reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

[How can I simulate a key press in a Python subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60502312/how-can-i-simulate-a-key-press-in-a-python-subprocess/60502586)

https://gist.github.com/waylan/2353749

When it enters Python prompt you can exit it by inputting `exit()`.

Something along the lines of this (if you don't care about realtime output):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["python", "my_file.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE shell=True)
output, error = p.communicate(input=b'exit()')
```

You need to modify this further if you want to have realtime output. The gist link should give you an idea how to read and write simultaneously.