# Is it possible to use win32 in python 3.8 for pressing keys on your keyboard

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32com, win32gui

I have created an app that presses some keys on the keyboard using pydirectinput. The problem is that pydirectinput is a bit slow and my app needs to be fast. Does anyone know how to make keypresses using win32 and if so, can you show me how to download and install it, and how to use it to press some keys on the keyboard. I am using python 3.8. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In win32, you can use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) simulate keyboard input.

In python, you can import the `ctypes` library to call `SendInput`.

A code sample:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import time

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

INPUT_MOUSE    = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2

KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008

MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0

# msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731
VK_TAB  = 0x09
VK_MENU = 0x12

# C struct definitions

wintypes.ULONG_PTR = wintypes.WPARAM

class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("dx",          wintypes.LONG),
                ("dy",          wintypes.LONG),
                ("mouseData",   wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("wVk",         wintypes.WORD),
                ("wScan",       wintypes.WORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(KEYBDINPUT, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        # some programs use the scan code even if KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE
        # isn't set in dwFflags, so attempt to map the correct code.
        if not self.dwFlags & KEYEVENTF_UNICODE:
            self.wScan = user32.MapVirtualKeyExW(self.wVk,
                                                 MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 0)

class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("uMsg",    wintypes.DWORD),
                ("wParamL", wintypes.WORD),
                ("wParamH", wintypes.WORD))

class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    class _INPUT(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (("ki", KEYBDINPUT),
                    ("mi", MOUSEINPUT),
                    ("hi", HARDWAREINPUT))
    _anonymous_ = ("_input",)
    _fields_ = (("type",   wintypes.DWORD),
                ("_input", _INPUT))

LPINPUT = ctypes.POINTER(INPUT)

def _check_count(result, func, args):
    if result == 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

user32.SendInput.errcheck = _check_count
user32.SendInput.argtypes = (wintypes.UINT, # nInputs
                             LPINPUT,       # pInputs
                             ctypes.c_int)  # cbSize

# Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode,
                            dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def AltTab():
    """Press Alt+Tab and hold Alt key for 2 seconds
    in order to see the overlay.
    """
    PressKey(VK_MENU)   # Alt
    PressKey(VK_TAB)    # Tab
    ReleaseKey(VK_TAB)  # Tab~
    time.sleep(2)
    ReleaseKey(VK_MENU) # Alt~

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AltTab()
```

This is a sample provided by [@lucasg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615802/11128312).

Comment: @PeanutInANutshell hi, you could feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it, if the answer does help.