# Simulate Win+D (Show Desktop) from Python Script

Tags: python, winapi

I want to minimize all open windows and / or show the desktop on a Windows 10 machine from within a python script. I had a look in the win32api, win32con, win32gui but cannot find anything appropriate.
Any idea appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyautogui is a great module for stimulating keyboard clicks and mouse clicks. To install it, try this command in the terminal. `pip install PyAutoGUI`

Using pyautogui, you can stimulate a virtual click in 2 ways. Choose which one works best for you:

1:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('winleft', 'd')
```

2:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('winleft')
pyautogui.press('d')
pyautogui.keyUp('winleft')
```

Sometimes the first one doesn't work, so if it doesn't, try the second one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use WinApi to implement keyboard emulation, you can use the [`keybd_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) function.

code:

```
import win32api 

win32api.keybd_event(0x5B, 0, ) # LWIN
win32api.keybd_event(0x44, 0, ) # D
win32api.keybd_event(0x5B, 0, 2) 
win32api.keybd_event(0x44, 0, 2)
```

Of course, you should probably use `SendInput`, but it is a bit complicated to use in python.

You can refer to this thread : [How to generate keyboard events in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python/13615802#13615802)