# Python keyboard to send int to TextField that only accepts numbers

Tags: python, user-interface, numeric, pyautogui

I'm developing a Python GUI to automate repetitive tasks. Within my firm's CRM app, I need to search for a number of clients and check whether they have updated certain information.

I'm encountering an issue as I'm not sure how to input numeric values (client IDs) into a search bar that only accepts strings.

Could someone please provide me with a hint or solution? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

I've tried with

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('num0')
pyautogui.typewrite('1')
```

but neither has solved my problem.

Comment: I think I solved it with the amazing piece of code I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events